# ROBOCOPY: Copy all subfolders+content without the content of the root directory

Tags: windows, robocopy, copy

I'm trying to copy all subfolders with their content of a specific folder but I don't want to copy the files in the root folder.
For example, if my folder look like:

```
- root
  - file.txt
  - sub1
    - another-file.txt
  - sub2
    - one-more.txt
```

I'd like to copy it to a new folder which will look as follows afterwards:

```
- target
  - sub1
    - another-file.txt
  - sub2
    - one-more.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible using a single `robocopy` execution. You will have to call it in a loop or use PowerShell, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a script:

```
for /D %%i in (S:\SourceDirectory\*.*) DO (
    robocopy %%i D:\DestinationDirectory\%%~ni /MIR
)
```

If you don't want to use the /MIR switch, you may need to experiment.